# Down cast child object in to parent object such that it has only parent attribute

Tags: java

I have two classes: `Child` and `Parent`. `Child` extends `Parent`. I created a `Child` object and set all parameters i.e. parameters of `Child` as well as that of `Parent`.

Now at run time I want a `Parent` object that has only `Parent` class attribute. Example classes are

```
public class Parent {

    private String lastName;

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Parent [lastName=" + lastName + "]";
    }

}
public class Child extends Parent{

    private String firstName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Child [firstName=" + firstName + ", getLastName()="
                + getLastName() + "]";
    }


}
public class TestExtension {


    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        Child child = new Child();
        child.setFirstName("fist name");
        child.setLastName("last name");
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        parent = (Parent) child;
        System.out.println(child);
        System.out.println(parent);
    }
}
```

Output is

```
Child [firstName=fist name, getLastName()=last name]
Child [firstName=fist name, getLastName()=last name]
```

Expected output I want to get:

```
Child [firstName=fist name, getLastName()=last name]
Parent [LastName=last name]
```

Answer (score 5):

Casting is not conversion. The object will always be a `Child`, whether you store it in a `Parent` reference or `Object` reference. Any call to `toString()` will call `Child.toString()` and you can't prevent that.

Your only choice is to create a method in `Child` that creates a `Parent` object and copies data to it (and returns it). That or change your requirements.

You're also not downcasting, you're upcasting and you don't need the explicit cast to `(Parent)`.

Comment: That's a good explanation. But I'm sure it's enough if he doesn't create a `Child` object to begin with (just do `new Parent()`)...

Comment: @ErnestKiwele but that wouldn't answer his question which is about getting a `Parent` object out of a `Child` object.

Comment: I am creating child object first.

Comment: @rakesh also in the programming world there is no inheritance relationship between a parent and a child, or would you say that every child is a parent?

Comment: @Kayaman You've already answered the question. But my point is that "creating" a `Parent` object from a `Child` object is pretty much an anti-pattern.

Comment: @Kayaman you are correct, I was wrong in this concept that every child is not parent. But is there any way that a parent can have attributes from the child that he have given to child.

Comment: Scenario I have is that I have a basic data bean and one is additional data bean. I have used additional data bean for my business logic but I have to return only basic details. What should be way to do that. instead of creating a new basic bean and explicitly setting the attributes in that. Bean i  created such that basic bean extends additional bean

Comment: @rakesh basic bean extends additional? Isn't that a bit backwards?

Comment: @Kayama yeah, but I though If I can bet back ward to return the response, As I do not have to update any parameter of the child bean then let go back ward and create it that. If you have any other approach then most welcome. I just want the better solution to this problem.

Comment: @rakesh proper code should work correctly even if a subclass is substituted where the superclass is required. It sounds like you've made this more complicated than it needs to be. Your example doesn't really tell anything about your **real** problem either. It just shows the flawed approach you took to solving your problem.

Comment: @Kayaman Apologies due to typo error in your name. 
Please suggest other approach, I just want a better solution to this scenario.

Comment: @rakesh well if your `AdditionalData extends BasicData`, then each additional is also a basic. Then you don't need to do anything. If you call methods that are overridden in `AdditionalData`, those will be called (like in your example). If that's something that's causing you problems, you need to work on that.

Comment: I am not calling any overridden method. I just wanted to control attributes

Comment: @rakesh you don't need to. A subclass has all the attributes its superclass has, provided there are getters for them.

Comment: then how i will be having access to only parent attributes. As java heap is giving me the child object, type casting is not changing the attributes to parent only.

Comment: No, but if you do `Parent p = child;`, you can't access child attributes through `p`. This is basic Java polymorphism.

Comment: then but parent p when i am printing using tostring then it is of child object and all parameters in that

Comment: @rakesh yes, but you said "I am not calling any overridden method.". Don't call `toString()`.

Answer (score 1):

The act of casting a reference of a base class(Parent) to one of its derived classes(Child) is downcasting. Need to remember that, it is possible to perform a safe downcasting, when a reference variable of the base class (parent class) has a value of the derived class (child class).

Depends on what behavior you require, and as long as we are happy with the behavior(method implementations of parent), there is no need to override the parent methods(behavior) , of the child class. To put simply,a proper inheritance hierarchy is required , and that's when Parent and Child make sense, and code reuse happens.

Thus, as per the code above, its not a downcast. its just that both the parent and child refer to the same object instance of child in memory.

```
Child child = new Child();
child.setFirstName("fist name");
child.setLastName("last name");
Parent parent = new Parent();
parent = child; // no need to be explicit with the casting , of Parent to child, make no difference.
```

**End result will be :**

```
Child [firstName=fist name, getLastName()=last name]
Child [firstName=fist name, getLastName()=last name]
```

This is obvious, again though we have two objects created they both refer to the same object or the child instance in memory.

The actual downcast is:

**Downcast Scenario 1:**

```
  Parent parent = new Child();
  Child child = (Child)parent;
  child.setFirstName("fist name");
  child.setLastName("last name");
  System.out.println(child);
  System.out.println(parent);
```

**End result will be :**

```
Child [firstName=fist name, getLastName()=last name]
Child [firstName=fist name, getLastName()=last name]
```

This is obvious, both the references point to same object in memory, though they are of different types.

**Exception Scenario:**

```
  Parent parent = new Parent();
  Child child = new Child();
  child = (Child)parent;
```

**End result will be :** ClassCastException , as Parent cannot be cast to Child.

Comment: Scenario I have is that I have a basic data bean and one is additional data bean. I have used additional data bean for my business logic but I have to return only basic details. What should be way to do that. instead of creating a new basic bean and explicitly setting the attributes in that. Bean i created such that basic bean extends additional bean

Comment: Please see the edit, I would recommend you design ur classes following object oriented principles, and use the right inheritance heirachy. To put it simply ,when we create an object it stays in the heap (using new) and what we get back is a reference to the heap. When we assign the references(be it a type of parent/child) , its still pointing to the actual object on heap.

Comment: but i wanted to use some encapsulation in order so control some attributes access. If you can suggest any other approach then your advice will be highly appriciated

Comment: If u create an instance of child, u can invoke all the methods of parent and child. Which method u can choose depends on the type of the reference variable(reference variable type Parent means u can invoke parent methods only). Which method will get executed depends on the actual object it refers to in heap (overridden method of child , if they both have the same name and argument types but implemented differently).  U should be able to choose, all protected and public variables of parent class in child class, Declare a method in parent, and implement in child and return parent attributes.

Answer (score 0):

For your expect:

```
Parent parent = new Parent();
parent.setLastName(child.getLastName);
System.out.println(parent);
```

Answer (score -1):

You are overriding the Parent's `toString()` method with the `child` class
and then you are doing a cast `parent = (Parent) child;`. 
To get what you want, add `super().toString()` inside the `toString()` method of the `child` class. Like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
return "Child [firstName=" + firstName + ", getLastName()="
        + getLastName() + "]"+super.toString();
}
```

But here again, printing only `child` is sufficient.